# Injecting a generic IList from spring.net

Tags: c#, enums, spring.net

I have an enumeration in the namespace Device.Control ...

```
public enum State {
    IN_PROGRESS, SUSPENDED, HALTED, FINISHED
}
```

And I have a class...

```
public class CustomStateManager {
    public IList<State> ManagingStates { get; set; } 
}
```

And here's my config XML for spring.net...

```
<object id="MyStateManager" type="CustomStateManager">
    <property name="ManagingStates">
        <list>
            <value>SUSPENDED</value>
            <value>HALTED</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</object>
```

After building and trying to inject the MyStateManager object, Spring.NET complains that it cannot set the ManagingStates property of the object.  I get this error...

> Error creating object with name 'MyStateManager' defined in 'file
>   [Spring.xml] line 3' : Error setting property values:
>   PropertyAccessExceptionsException (1 errors); nested
>   PropertyAccessExceptions are: [Spring.Core.TypeMismatchException:
>   Cannot convert property value of type [System.Collections.ArrayList]
>   to required type
>   [System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[SandboxConsole.Device.Control.ApplicationEnumerations+State,
>   SandboxConsole, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]] for property 'ManagingStates'., Inner
>   Exception: Spring.Core.TypeMismatchException: Cannot convert property
>   value of type [System.Collections.ArrayList] to required type
>   [System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[SandboxConsole.Device.Control.ApplicationEnumerations+State,
>   SandboxConsole, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]] for property 'ManagingStates'...

I am a little new to Spring.NET and I cannot figure out what the problem here is, other than it cannot inject an ArrayList into the IList property.  **Is it possible to create lists in the configuration where values are enumerated types?  If so, how?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the `element-type`:

```
<list element-type="Namespace.State, Assembly">
    <value>SUSPENDED</value>
    <value>HALTED</value>
</list>
```

where *Namespace* is the namespace of your class and *Assembly* the assembly that contains your enum.

```
<list element-type="SandboxConsole.Device.Control.ApplicationEnumerations+State, SandboxConsole">
    <value>SUSPENDED</value>
    <value>HALTED</value>
</list>
```

*ApplicationEnumerations+State* because you try to access an inner class.

http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-generic-collections-values